# JSON.parse error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am retrieving values from server side code and here is my value ..

```
["INCOMING",09:09:49,"INETCALL",00:14:09,"ISD",00:05:50,"LOCAL",02:38:02,"STD",01:39:28]
```

Now as per my need i want to parse it into JSON but on parsing it is giving error..

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element

var dbdata=JSON.parse(data);
```

and here is my code to get value from server side and parse it into json..

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'getdataduration',
                async:false,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {

                    var dbdata=JSON.parse(data);

                    for(var i=0,len=dbdata.length;i<len;i++){
                        $.isNumeric(dbdata[i]) ?  callduration.push(dbdata[i]) :  toc.push(dbdata[i]);
                    }
                }

            });
```

Please guys help me.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: The problem is because the value from your server isn't JSON, it's an array.

Comment: The response isn't valid. `09:09:49` and other times aren't supported as literals and should be quoted.

Comment: if you are using php in server side... send response as json with `echo json_encode();` . the response you are getting is not JSON... that is an array

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sir if i put time 00:14:09 as "00:14:09" then will it be parsed

Comment: That's correct. By adding the quotes it becomes a valid JSON format, and can be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

The value from your server isn't JSON fromat, it's array!
The JSON format reference:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON

I think you should generate the data from your server like this:

```
[{"INCOMING"："09:09:49","INETCALL"："00:14:09","ISD"："00:05:50","LOCAL"："02:38:02","STD"："01:39:28"}]
```

Comment: I'd remove the outer square brackets, then it's probably what the data is trying to convey.

Comment: if single object,remove;object list,remain

Answer (score 1):

The value is not valid JSON nor is it valid JS. Every second elemt is invalid

E.g `09:09:49` is not valid it should (probably) be `"09:09:49"`

The below is a valid array and can be parsed with JSON.parse

```
["INCOMING","09:09:49","INETCALL","00:14:09","ISD","00:05:50","LOCAL","02:38:02","STD","01:39:28"]
```

an easy way to test these kinds of issues is to dump the server reply into the browser development console and see what errors if any that produce

Answer (score 0):

change your data to below format

```
  ["INCOMING","09:09:49","INETCALL","00:14:09","ISD","00:05:50","LOCAL","02:38:02","STD","01:39:28"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test easily the validty of a JSON with this web tool:

http://jsonlint.com/

```
Parse error on line 2:
...    "INCOMING",    09: 09: 49,    "INE
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

As bipen says, if you use PHP, send your data using json_encode(); and put json as datatype in your $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

**Correct JSON Data:**

```
// you should create your json like this
var data = '[{
        "INCOMING" : "09: 09: 49",
        "INETCALL" : "00: 14: 09",
        "ISD" : "00: 05: 50",
        "LOCAL" : "02: 38: 02",
        "STD" : "01: 39: 28"
    }
]';
```

**Correct Ajax use with JSON:**

```
// use 'type: post' and 'dataType: json'. Because, post is safe and 
you are dealing with json data so it must be dataType: json
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'getdataduration',
    async : false,
    dataType : "JSON",
    success : function (data) {
        var dbdata = JSON.parse(data);
        for (var i = 0, len = dbdata.length; i < len; i++) {
            $.isNumeric(dbdata[i].YOUR_JSON_KEY)
            ? callduration.push(dbdata[i].YOUR_JSON_KEY) 
            : toc.push(dbdata[i].YOUR_JSON_KEY);
        }
    }
});
```

**Conclusion:**

```
You are using '$.isNumeric(dbdata[i])' but, as your json data your 
first value is string. So it's not gonna to work.
```